# Sphinx graphviz inheritance diagram increase node size

Tags: python, diagram, graphviz, python-sphinx

I'm trying to generate an inheritance diagram in Sphinx using the [sphinx.ext.inheritance_diagram](http://sphinx-doc.org/ext/inheritance.html) extension. This uses Graphviz to draw the diagrams.

It's not a huge diagram and it seems that there is enough space to increase the size of the nodes so they are readable. However I cannot get Graphviz to do so. I've tried increasing/decreasing the font size, width, height, size, etc. but non of my efforts made the diagram readable.

In my `conf.py` I have:

```
inheritance_graph_attrs = dict(rankdir="TB", ratio='fill')
```

And to generate an inheritance diagram for a module I included the following directive in the appropriate `rst` file:

```
.. inheritance-diagram:: package.module
```

This gives me the following diagram:

[image: generated diagram]

Increasing the size of the nodes should do the trick I think, but I just cannot figure out how to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much experience but I'd say the problem is that it "detects" only three horizontal levels. The font size is calculated automatically based on the available space. You must somehow get him to distribute the nodes at more than three levels... Without a concrete example it's difficult to say more since I cannot try myself.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://sphinx-doc.org/ext/inheritance.html) seems to suggest you can use these:

- `inheritance_graph_attrs`: A dictionary of graphviz graph attributes for inheritance diagrams.
- `inheritance_node_attrs`: A dictionary of graphviz node attributes for inheritance diagrams.
- `inheritance_edge_attrs`: A dictionary of graphviz edge attributes for inheritance diagrams.

Answer (score 0):

You should set parameter size in inheritance_graph_attrs  in conf.py, e.g.:

```
inheritance_graph_attrs = dict(fontsize=12, size='"16.0, 20.0"')
```

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old post, but since I stumbled on it in while trying to generate sphinx documentation with customized inheritance graphs, I thought I would include an answer that would have helped me a few days ago. The resource that was most helpful for me in generating inheritance diagrams and changing how they looked was in the [Graphviz](https://graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html) documentation that is very helpful in setting these parameters.

The table labels each attribute, the components that use that attribute, and the values of the component for the name-value pair. So for each:

```
inheritance_graph_attrs = G
inheritance_node_attrs = N
inheritance_edge_attrs = E
```

Therefore, you can set the size of the nodes in inches by using:

```
inheritance_node_attrs = {height=1, width=1}
```

Where the initial height and width of the node would be 1 inch, unless more room is required. You can also see every attribute that can be changed in Graphviz and how to change them in your conf.py file.